# Launch a process with elevated or non-elevated mode

Tags: c#

I check Vista Elevator source code on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/VistaElevator.aspx but it's in C++. Anyone has it in C# source code. Thanks.

I have a big problem:
How a non-elevated process can start an elevated process.
And how an elevated process can start an non-elevated process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the linked page,

> If a non-elevated process needs to start an elevated one, all it has to do is call the ShellExecuteEx() API and supply the "runas" verb as one of its parameters.

So all you need in C# is:

- [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)
- [ProcessStartInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)
- [ProcessStartInfo.Verb Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb.aspx)

Comment: Otherwise, how a elevated process start an non-elevated one. Thanks.

Comment: It seems there is no direct way to let an elevated process start a non-elevated one. The linked page describes a workaround, but I'm not sure it is a good idea to abuse the Task Scheduler for this.

Comment: You are wrong. You can check Vista Elevator source code, It has this feature.

Because I have a setup project, after start setup with elevated, It will need invoke the main application with non-elevated.