# delete file throw exception UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete file after I copy the file but I have this exception

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\---\Downloads\file.zip' is denied.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
       at CleanDownloadFolder.Program.CopyDirectory(String sourcePath, String targetPath) in c:\Users\Abdalla\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CleanDownloadFolder\CleanDownloadFolder\Program.cs:line 48
       at CleanDownloadFolder.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Abdalla\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CleanDownloadFolder\CleanDownloadFolder\Program.cs:line 16
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 


C# code
     if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".zip")
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                            System.IO.File.Delete(s);
                        }
```

Comment: have you tried running your application as Administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown because your application doesn't have the sufficient rights in order to delete the file at `Downloads`. You can either:

1. Spawn a new process of your own under Administrator, using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` namespace. For more information, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174728/launch-a-process-with-elevated-or-non-elevated-mode).
2. Download your file to another directory where you have the right to delete any file, such as the `AppData` directory.

You can get the path of AppData using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`, and then create a directory for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `UAC` enabled and you are not running your application as an `"Administrator"` you usually don't have access to delete from the system drive.

have you tried copying the file to some other location (`like D:`) and deleting

also you might find this interesting

[How does Read-Only affect a Directory when using C#/.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192956/how-does-read-only-affect-a-directory-when-using-c-net)

Comment: That would be true for a file in the root; this file is in the C:\Users\... profile dir.